# Assuming continuity of $f$, how does one prove uniform continuity of $f$, assuming the limit to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ is $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Assuming continuity of $f$, how does one go about proving uniform continuity of $f$, assuming the limit to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ is $0$?

Note: $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Looking for hints, not solutions. Thanks. I'm having trouble getting from a closed interval being bounded, to the entire function being bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Use the fact that continuity implies uniform continuity on any compact set,  find a suitable set $[-N,N]$ and a patching overlap set $[N-1,\infty),(-\infty,-N+1)$ to get overlapping uniform continuity

Comment: Am I right in assuming these patching overlap sets should use the fact that the limit of the function is 0 at + and - infinity?

I already got to the whole [-N,N] part, I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about the boundedness of the overlap, I guess. Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: Start your demonstration with $\epsilon >0$. Then use the fact that the limit at infinity is 0

Comment: Yes, without the limit going to 0 at $\pm \infty$, this doesn't hold.    However, the general method of proving uniform continuity over a large interval by breaking it up into overlapping smaller intervals does work in any case.